# Convergence of the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(n! \pi m \sin(1))$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, fourier-series

In this exercise I was asked to prove the convergence of the following infinite sum:  $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sin(n! \pi m \sin(1)),$$  where $m$ denotes any integer.
I don't have any idea on how to approach such problem, so I would be very grateful if you could explain your solution.

Comment: Note that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin{( n!\pi m \sin{(1)} )}$ does not exist.

Comment: One problem with those comments: $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \sin{( n!\pi m \sin{(1)} )}=0.$

Comment: Nice exercise. What a shame that we lack any kind of personal input from the OP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $n$ is odd, then

$$\pi n!\sin 1 = \pi n!(1 - 1/3! + 1/5! - \cdots ) = \pi\cdot (\text {integer} + r_n),$$

where

$$|r_n|< 1/[(n+2)(n+1)] + 1/[(n+4)(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)] + \cdots$$ $$ < 1/[(n+2)(n+1)] + 1/[(n+2)(n+1)]^2 + 1/[(n+2)(n+1)]^3 + \cdots = 1/[(n+2)(n+1)-1].$$

It follows that for large $n$ odd,

$$ |\sin (\pi n!\sin 1)| < \pi/[(n+2)(n+1)-1]$$

for large $n.$ So if we were summing over just odd $n,$ we would have absolute convergence. But we have the even terms to worry about, and those seem more subtle. So there's more work to do, but this is a start.

Comment: Indeed, using exactly your approach, one can see that the even terms yield an alternating series, convergent (as every alternating series) but not absolutely convergent. +1.

Comment: Very nice, thanks :)

Comment: A solid approach.  Well done. +1

Answer (score 0):

[A supplement about n is even. Please correct me if I have misconsidered anything.]

If $n$ is even, $r_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots$~or~$-\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}-\cdots$.

Assume that $r_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)(n+3)}+\cdots$,

then $r_{n+2}=-\frac{1}{n+3}+\frac{1}{(n+3)(n+4)(n+5)}+\cdots$.

Therefore, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_n$ can be written as $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_n=C_n+D_n,$

where $C_n=\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{n+3}+\cdots$ and $D_n$ is absolutely convergent.

It is easy to see that $C_n$ is an alternating series and conditionally convergent.

Thus, $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}r_n$ is conditionally convergent.

Comment: This is a complement to the first answer.